# Laravel - How to store a return from a function to the database?

Tags: database, laravel, function, model-view-controller

I'm new to Laravel. I'm having problems with storing data to the database. I have for instance this:

create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'WebsitesController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::label('url', 'URL')}}
      {{Form::text('url', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'URL'])}}
    </div>
    {{lol()}}
    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

WebsitesController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'url' => 'required'
      ]);

      $website = new Website;
      $website->path = $request->input('url');
      $website->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
      $website->save();
    }
```

This works. Now I want instead of getting the url from the input to get it from a function. Let's say I have a function like this:

```
function testurl(){
    return "http://test.com/";
}
```

Where do I put my function code? And how do I get $website->path to store the return of that function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your function in controller like

```
    public function testUrl(){
    return "http://test.com/";
    }
```

and if you are calling it in same controller, you can do

```
$url = $this->testUrl();
```

if you are calling from other controller, you can do

```
$url = $yourController->testUrl();
```

You can then directly set

```
$website->path=$url
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Why do I need the Website Model?

Comment: The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a  simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.

Comment: @AarifAslam, just sharing a good practice. Make this `testUrl` method `private`.

Answer (score 0):

`Website()` is your model. You can store your function inside of your model. So you can call it directly from your model.